# Checking the periodicity of a signal

Tags: fourier-transform, signal-processing, periodic-functions

We're given this signal:

$X_a(t) = x(t)\cdot rect(\frac{t}{100})$, where $x(t) = cos(3t)$

And we have to check if it's periodic or not, and find the period if it is.

Now, for $cos(3t)$, the period $T_A$ is $\frac{2π}{ω_1} = \frac{2π}{3}$.

For $rect(\frac{t}{100})$, we can use Fourier transformation to get $100sinc(100πf)$, if I'm not mistaken.

But then I don't know how to continue. What do i do from here?

Answer (score 1):

If your rect function is defined as 
$$\operatorname{rect}(t) =
\begin{cases}
 0, & \text{if } |t| > \frac{1}{2} \\
 \frac{1}{2}, & \text{if } |t| = \frac{1}{2} \\
 1, & \text{if } |t| < \frac{1}{2}.
\end{cases}$$
So
$$\operatorname{rect}(\frac{t}{100}) =
\begin{cases}
 0, & \text{if } |t| > 50 \\
 \frac{1}{2}, & \text{if } |t| = 50 \\
 1, & \text{if } |t| < 50.
\end{cases}$$ 
Then your periodicity is ruined because of this rect function.

Comment: Thank you. Since we're not given an exact definition of the rect function, but we're assuming, is this sufficient as an answer?

Comment: @Ahmad Why suggesting $$rect(t) = \frac{1}{2}, |t| = \frac{1}{2} $$?